# In .NET CORE, How to perform XUnit test to check and validate correct information loading from AppSetting.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I am working on XUnit Test with Specification for SendGrid Azure, running in .NET CORE application. I am new to testing world so a lot to understand philosophy behind it.

I am EmailService class responsible to perform Email send functionalities.

In my first test I want to check if correct configuration been loaded from appsetting.json file.

### appsetting.json

```
 "SendGridEmailSettings": {
 "SendGrid_API_Key": "xxx",
 "SenderConfig": {
   "From": "info@myOrganization.ltd",
   "Name": "my organization"
 }
}
```

### Test Class

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions;

namespace Services.Specs
{
  public class EmailServiceSpec: Specification
  {

    protected override void Observe()
    {
        var configuration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
        Bag.Configuration = configuration;
    }
}

public class EmailServiceShould: EmailServiceSpec
{
    public EmailServiceShould()
    {
        Observe();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Load_Valid_Configuration_From_AppSetting()
    {
        //var SendGrid_API_Key = Configuration["SendGridEmailSettings:SendGrid_API_Key"]; this doesn't work
    }
 }
}
```

### email service config class

```
public interface IEmailConfig
{
     string SendGrid_API_Key { get; set; }
    SenderEmailConfig SenderConfig { get; set; }
}
```

### email Service class

```
 public interface IEmailService
{       
    Task SendEmail(EmailMultipleAudience email);
    Task SendEmail(EmailSingleAudience email);
}

public class EmailData
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string PlainTextContent { get; set; }
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
}

public class EmailSingleAudience: EmailData
{
    public EmailAddress To { get; set; }
}

public class EmailMultipleAudience : EmailData
{
    public List<EmailAddress> To { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Build an actual configuration and use that, It would be a lot simpler than trying to mock it. But technically you are just testing that Microsoft's code works, which I believe they would have tested before releasing it. So what is the real purpose of testing this?

Comment: You should be using `IOptions<T>` for configuration that is loaded from appsettings.json.

Comment: sure, I want to test sendGrid load correct API Key from config test 2) send test email with given configuration and it did worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your `appsettings.json` inside your XUnit test project if you have a separate project (Otherwise skip this step). Then load it:

```
var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
```

Then you can use it.

```
var SendGrid_API_Key = Configuration["SendGridEmailSettings:SendGrid_API_Key"];
```